# Add coloured text to Python Shell 3.6.1

Tags: python, colors

Okay, I wonder if it's possible to add coloured text to a singular line in Python 3.6.1 or higher? (or less?)
For example, I want to change 'Elite' to orange in this code;

```
print("Elite")
print("You got KBAR-99")
```

Also, is it possible for it to turn to default text when it prints 'You got KBAR-99?)

Comment: Colorized text is a feature of the shell you are running Python in. Which do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANSI color codes:

```
print("\033[33m" + "Elite" + "\033[0m")
```

or `import colorama`.

Answer (score 0):

Very much depends on your terminal. If the terminal understands ANSI control codes you can use of those modules that generates ANSI color codes. [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama), for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for colouring and formatting the output of your Python scripts. The first, and most basic, is using a module like [`rich`](https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich). The alternative, like @Błotosmętek said  is to use ANSI break codes.